# How to get exactly same accelaration curve on Windows as in Mac OS X? Intercept mouse accel?

Tags: windows, macos, mouse, acceleration

In work we have MacOSx everywhere. In home, I have Win10. And I really really like acceleration curve on mac osx (maybe not for mouse, but I use trackball, and it works perfectly). 
How can I make, to seamlessly transfer between Mac/Win without changing my acceleration curve?
I searched on internet, but it seems like everyone want opposite thing (to have win curve on mac).
I have this app: Intercept mouse accel, where I can change accel curves, but I can't make it simmilar to Mac osx, and im trying for a while :-)

Answer (score 2):

The free
[Mouse Acceleration](https://mouseacceleration.com/)
could help you create an exact acceleration curve on Windows.

[image]